# I change Voltage from 220V to 110V

Tags: power-supply, dell-optiplex

My dell pc Power Supply uses 220V and my country standard too. And i chage the Voltage from 220v to 110 V at the back of PSU. And suddenly  makes sound and smokes after that its stops working. 
chance  to repair the power supply unit  Or buy new?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, definitely time to get a new PSU. Hopefully that was the only thing damaged, but you won't be able to tell until you get a working PSU in there.

Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

You've destroyed your PSU. Time to buy a new one.

By switching the input selector from 240V -> 110V, you were telling the PSU "The input voltage is only 110V now."

Except it wasn't 110V. You're still in a country with a 220V supply, so you effectively gave it twice the voltage it was expecting.

Hence the smoke.

On the plus side, at least now you know what that switch does!

Comment: it may be an idea to remove that pic.  Some people might not realise that that kind of damage is not realistic, and this photo is not "real" (ie a power supply cant just burst into flames like that)

Comment: It was a great pic though!  

Comment: PSUs can catch fire. It's not common but there are numerous documented instances of it happening: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/982932-evga-psu-lit-my-house-on-fire-/

Comment: Clicked on link. Was disappointed. Ni evidencr if PSU burning. (not really a surprise. Metal does not burn)

Comment: It isn't the metal chassis that catches fire but the components, which mostly consist of non-metal elements. The poster even stated: "Insurance took the entire set up as evidence, fire inspectors confirmed it was the power supply. Is this common?? " Forensic investigators confirmed it was the power supply. If something is capable of smoking, it's capable of burning at a high enough temperature. This is why server room fire suppression systems exist.

Comment: Should be labeled the auto destruct switch!

Comment: @wrecclesham Absolutely a PSU/computer can be the catalist to start a fire.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably cheaper to buy a new PSU because of labour costs, but if you live in a country where labour is cheap you may be able to get it repaired more cheaply.  **No one can answer this definitively**

At a wild guess there is a capacitor that went bang.   If you replace the capacitor you could be fine, but playing inside a PSU is supposed to be a bad idea...  (In other words lots of people recommend against it)

Comment: It's a desktop. Laptops don't have voltage input selectors on them.

Comment: @wrecclesham of-course (doh!)